# Magento2: How to uninstall sample data from database

Tags: magento2, database, sample-data

Does anyone know how we can remove the sample data from the database?

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Note: I don't want to remove the sample data modules, I'm looking for something that can help me to remove all the sample data entries from the database.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

After complete these steps, the sample data should be uninstalled from your Magento 2 database.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento sampledata:remove
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```